# CollectionView snap item layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am trying to find an approach for `CollectionView` to snap items center point to the center of the screen

In this screenshot vertical **black** line is center of the screen, item 1 is centered and next item 2 should be centered after swiping

[image]